# Extra weapons differences

Tags: bayonetta

Is there some difference on buying the weapon and getting it with the angelic LP? (e.g. Durga)
When the weapon is available for buy with halos, it’s an altered version of the original one?

Answer (score 3):

As I recall, all the weapons that you can both buy with Halos and get from LPs can be worn on the hands ***or*** feet.
The LP will give you one set, but you'll have to buy a 2nd set if you want to equip the same weapon to ***both*** hands and feet.